# How to compute eigenvector for rank 1 matrix without high complexity SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am sorry for asking probably well known or trivial problem.

> How to compute eigenvector for rank 1 matrix, say $A = ab^* \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ without performing high complexity SVD ($A = U \Sigma V^*$)?

---

I understand that the eigenvalue $\lambda $ of such rank 1 matrix is either $b^*a$ or $0$. But how to find the appropriate eigenvector $Ax = \lambda x$, where $x$ is an eigenvector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $b^*a$ is just $a$; $Aa=(ab^*)a=a(b^*a)$. That's just the associative law for matrix products - note that the product of a $n\times 1$ times a $1\times 1$ is the same as vector space scalar multiplication.

In practice, if we don't have it written that way already? Pick a column of the rank-1 matrix (preferably one that's not identically zero). It's a multiple of the eigenvector.